# Middleman server will not start, regexp has invalid internal

Tags: ruby, middleman

I have moved hosting providers and reinstalled ruby and middleman.

When I run `bundle exe middleman server` I get:

> /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/haml-4.0.4/lib/haml/parser.rb:86: warning: regexp has invalid interval
>   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-s3_sync-3.0.21/lib/middleman-s3_sync.rb:2:in `require': /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-s3_sync-3.0.21/lib/middleman/s3_sync.rb:54: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
>           @progress_bar ||= ProgressBar.create(total: paths.length)
>                                                      ^
>   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-s3_sync-3.0.21/lib/middleman/s3_sync.rb:54: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
>   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-s3_sync-3.0.21/lib/middleman/s3_sync.rb:67: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting kEND
>   ...                             .reject { |p| File.directory?(p...
>                                 ^
>   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-s3_sync-3.0.21/lib/middleman/s3_sync.rb:137: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-s3_sync-3.0.21/lib/middleman-s3_sync.rb:2
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`require'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in`each'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in`each'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in`require'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-core-3.2.0/lib/middleman-core/load_paths.rb:38:in `setup_load_paths'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-core-3.2.0/bin/middleman:10
>       from /usr/local/bin/middleman:19:in`load'
>       from /usr/local/bin/middleman:19

My Ruby knowledge is very poor, but when I look at the code I do not see a syntax error. I have had a look at the s3_sync git hub code and this part of the code has not changed in some time. I suspect this is an encoding issue, however I am a bit stuck in trying to fix it. Any light you can shed will be very helpful.

Additional info: I have tried on Ruby 1.8 and 1.9.3. And This is on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Seems that Middleman uses the newer JavaScript style Hash syntax (`total: paths.length` vs `:total => paths.length`) so it won't work with Ruby 1.8, should be fine with 1.9.3 though.

Comment: Thank you, why not add an answer so I can give you credit for solving this.

Comment: I'm capped out for the day so I was hoping someone else would :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SyntaxError seems to be complaining about this inside Middleman:

```
ProgressBar.create(total: paths.length)
```

The `/var/lib/gems/1.8/` path indicates that you're using Ruby 1.8.X. But the JavaScript-style Hash notation:

```
total: paths.length
```

doesn't work in 1.8, you have to use the `:total => paths.length` notation there. Looks like you can't use that version of Middleman with 1.8.7, either upgrade to 1.9.3+ or downgrade your Middleman to something that works with older Rubies.