# "regexp has invalid interval" when trying to compile with Sass

Tags: regex, sass

I have a very simple file:

```
h1 {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    &.small {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}
```

I then enter the following to compile the code sass `test.scss`. However I receive the following error message and no CSS file is created.

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.3.14/bin/../lib/sass/script/lexer.rb:343: warning: regexp has invalid interval
```

Any idea of what I may be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Cannot confirm with [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/gist/a82fc71b18e1a121b4d8), compiling under 3.3.14.  Wonder if this might be a Ruby version issue, since I had to upgrade to 1.9.3 at some point for either Sass or Compass.

Comment: @Unihedron There is no regex in Sass, this is a problem within Sass itself.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940993/middleman-server-will-not-start-regexp-has-invalid-internal

Comment: Any idea as to what the issue is within Sass?

Comment: As I already suggested, this is likely a Ruby version issue, meaning you should probably *try upgrading Ruby*.  Sass is *supposed* to work with 1.8 according to their gem file.  If upgrading solves the problem, you should report it to them on github.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a '}' without escape in a regular expression in /lib/sass/script/lexer.rb see  [the fix in github](https://github.com/sass/sass/commit/907e36f6724470bf7f38cfed7ae2539a38b51af9) you have to update to the latest version of sass (or at least 3.4.1).